# Spring Neo4j Data is destroying db on every deploy

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `neo4j` version `1.8.1` and `spring-data-neo4j` version `2.2.0. RELEASE`

Here is my spring neo4j configration;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db"/>
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="net.myPackage.core"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
</beans>
```

The db in the location which is given in spring context (target/neo4j-db), is being destroyed and created again. So this is a problem on production. On every deploying, product datas are removed from neo4j because of this problem.

How can I fix this? Is there a status that is checking this that can I set in spring context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe problem with `storeDirectory`? Maybe it removed by your development IDE? Try to move store directory outside target folder.

Comment: Your database directory is in 'target' which means cleaned by maven at every `clean` or deploy task. :)

Comment: Thank you. Moving db path in target to another directory is what I was missing :)